# Split plot anova on R with repeated measures

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am trying to fit a two way anova from an experiment with a split-split-plot design.

The experimental design is as follows:

I have 6 sites (fixed factor). Inside each site I have a random effect of Plot nested within Site and Subplot nested within plot. Within each subplot, I measured PW variables (such as salinity) every Season (fixed factor treated as the repeated measure).

Therefore, I have 2 fixed factors (Site and Season), I have plot (random effect) nested within site and subplot nested within plot. Season is my repeated measurement.

I want to understand how Site and Season, and their interaction affects my PW variables (e.g., Salinity).

I would like to find a code on R that will allow me to specify Season as my repeated measure and specify my nesting structure. I would also like to run a Tukey's Pairwise comparison test afterwards on R.

I tried the following code considering my nesting structure; however, Site is considered random in this code because it is in the error term, while site should be fixed.

```
sal_model <- aov(Salinity_ppt ~ Site * Season+ Error(Site/Plot/Subplot), data = new_dataset) 
summary(sal_model)

Warning message:
In aov(Salinity_ppt ~ Site * Season + Error(Site/Plot/Subplot),  :
  Error() model is singular
> summary(sal_model)

Error: Site
     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Site  5   3261   652.2

Error: Site:Plot
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  6  201.8   33.63               

Error: Site:Plot:Subplot
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 36  250.5   6.959               

Error: Within
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Season        1   2936  2936.3 125.306  < 2e-16 ***
Site:Season   5    726   145.2   6.196 2.65e-05 ***
Residuals   170   3984    23.4                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I also tried the following code which does not include Site in the error term, therefore does not consider plot being nested within site, but it does consider site to be a fixed factor.

```
sal_model <- aov(Salinity_ppt ~ Site * Season+ Error(Plot/Subplot), data = new_dataset)
Warning message:
In aov(Salinity_ppt ~ Site * Season + Error(Plot/Subplot), data = new_dataset) :
  Error() model is singular
> summary(sal_model)

Error: Plot
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1   5.98    5.98               

Error: Plot:Subplot
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  6  45.98   7.664               

Error: Within
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Site          5   3261   652.2  30.500  < 2e-16 ***
Season        1   2936  2936.3 137.305  < 2e-16 ***
Site:Season   5    726   145.2   6.789 7.01e-06 ***
Residuals   205   4384    21.4                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

With both codes I get the following error:

Warning message:
In aov(Salinity_ppt ~ Site * Season + Error(Plot/Subplot), data = new_dataset) :
Error() model is singular

Given my experimental design, is there a code on R that i can apply a two way anova model that specifies my split plot design and repeated measure?